# Prevent user from going on another view if he is on particular url and does not pass a test

Tags: python, django, decorator

I am working on a django project where I am required to prevent user from entering in another view if

1. he is on a perticular page
2. Does not passes a test

If he is on a specific page. If user is on another page but he does not pass test, he will be allowed to go anywhere.

For example If I have three tabs `Tab1`, `Tab2` and `Tab3`. If user is on `Tab2` and does not pass a test `A`, he cannot go on `Tab1` and `Tab3`. But if he is on `Tab1` or `Tab3` but he does not passes that test, he can still goes to `Tab2` and `Tab3`. 
When user will click `Tab1` I want to check whether he is on `Tab2`  or not. If he is not, he will be allowed to go. But If he is on `Tab2`, I will check whether user passes test or not. If he passes that test, he will be allowed to go. Otherwise he will not be allowed to go.

I tried to use `@user_passes_test` decorator but it takes user as argument and I cannot get current url. Is there any other way of doing this or any other decorator which I can use? Or I have to write my own custom decorator?

Comment: why don't you put decorator only on view where user is restricted to enter if he does not pass the test. That way he can go to any page but is restricted only to the page(or view) where decorated is used.

For eg: You can put decorator on Tab1 and not on Tab2 so that user can easily enter Tab2 but need to pass test to enter Tab1

Comment: He is restricted to go every where if he is on particular view and does not passes test. I can check whether user passes test or not with `user_passes_test` but I cannot check whether he is on particular view or not.

Comment: Can I ask why the current url matters at all? is the test not enough?

Comment: @Sayse As I mention in example "If I have three tabs Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3. If user is on Tab2 and does not pass a test A, he cannot go on Tab1 and Tab3. But if he is on Tab1 or Tab3 but he does not passes that test, he can still goes to Tab2 and Tab3". When user will click `Tab1` I want to check whether he is on `Tab2`  or not. If he is not, he will be allowed to go. But If he is on `Tab2`, I will check whether user passes test or not. If he passes that test, he will be allowed to go. Otherwise he will not be allowed to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by create a middleware ,
On middleware  just check user's forward url by request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER',None).
Then check test entry if user attempt test exist in db then pass or return a error page or what you want.

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    referer_path = str(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER',None))
    request_path = str(request.path)        
    match_pattern = r"[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}"

    if re.search(match_pattern, request_path) and request_path.__contains__('/lms/media/video/articulate/') and response.status_code == 200:
         #what you want logic
```

For more detail follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: But middleware class will be called every time when HttpRequest will be send to the server. And I have many ajax requests in my page. This will increase overhead.

Comment: if you just want to check on particular view. then you can create a decorator and call same script on request object :)
You can also handle this on javascript. its depend on your scenario.

Comment: Thanx. I have written a custom decorator which resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a custom decorator which takes `request` object as input with the help of which I checked current location and check if user passes specific tests or not.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def request_passes_test(test_func, redirect_url=None, message=None, status=401):
"""
Decorator for resources that checks that the request passes the given test.
If the request fails the test a 401 (Unauthorized) response is returned,
otherwise the view is executed normally. The test should be a callable that
takes an HttpRequest object and any number of positional and keyword
arguments as defined by the urlconf entry for the decorated resource.
"""
    def decorator(view_func):
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not test_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator
```

It can be uses as

```
@request_passes_test(test_function, redirect_url='/url/')
```